# How to flip the order of the Google Chart legends?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Currently, my google pie chart displays as so:

[image]

How would I go about switching the order of the legends, so that Positive comes first?

[My code @ jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifaxey/edit#preview).

Comment: if you invert 'pos' and 'neg' on the code?

Comment: The pie flips, which I don't want.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @MCSI here http://jsbin.com/ifaxey/edit#preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the current API, this is simply not possible. My solution was to disable the API's legends and implement my own using css.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://jsbin.com/ifaxey/3/edit

i've flipped the array and the colors.

this is what you really want?

Comment: No, that's the thing: The positives need to be on the left side, ie Green part of the chart needs to be on the left side, as well as the "Positive" legend. I already tried what you suggest. :)